# How to get full path all the way to root in CTreeCtl in MFC

Tags: mfc

I am populating a tree control with directories and subdirectories from a ftp server. I already have the code working but just cant get the full path.
How do I get the full path all the way to root of a selected sub directory when I double click the tree item. Am I going to have to manually do this?

ex..

```
ROOT
     FOLDER A 1
           FOLDER A 2
     FOLDER B 1
```

So if I click on FOLDER A 2, how can I get the path /ROOT/FOLDER A 1/FOLDER A 2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you show us some sample code that puts your request 'in context', then you will probably get one or more good answers that show you how to achieve your goal.

Comment: Also, have you considered using `CMFCShellTreeCtrl` - specifically designed for use with files and folders.

Answer (score 2):

A [CTreeCtrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctreectrl-class) provides basic control functionality. Implementing the business logic is on you. To get a path to the root item, you will have to concatenate the individual path parts. You can do this at different times:

#### When populating the control

A tree item allows you to store custom data alongside the display text. When populating the tree control you can store a pointer to your data (e.g. a string with the full path) by setting the `lParam` parameter in a call to [CTreeCtrl::InsertItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctreectrl-class#insertitem). You can later retrieve it calling [CTreeCtrl::GetItemData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctreectrl-class#getitemdata).

#### On demand

You can alternatively construct the full path on demand by traversing the tree structure all the way to the root element, concatenating each path part along the way. The following code serves as a starting point:

```cpp
CStringW PathFromItem(CTreeCtrl const& tree, HTREEITEM hItem)
{
    CStringW path{ tree.GetItemText(hItem) };
    while (hItem = tree.GetParentItem(hItem))
    {
        path = tree.GetItemText(hItem) + L"\\" + path;
    }
    path = tree.GetItemText(tree.GetRootItem()) + L"\\" + path;
    return path;
}
```

#### Alternative

As an alternative you should evaluate, whether [CMFCShellTreeCtrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcshelltreectrl-class) works for you. It displays a hierarchy of Shell items, and can be confined to including file system items only.